# How to deal with thrift client disconnection issue

Tags: python, hbase, connection-pooling, thrift, reconnect

My project use bottle and HBase, client connect to HBase via python thrift client, code simplify like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bottle import route, run, default_app, request

client = HBaseClient()

@route('/', method='POST')
def index():
    data = client.getdata()
    return data
```

Now the issue is if client disconnect, our request will be failed. So it requires to make sure client keep alive.

One solution is using connection pool, is there any connection pool I can refer to?

Any other solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks [happybase](http://happybase.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) can deal this issue

Answer (score 0):

HappyBase has a connection pool that tries to deal with broken connections to some extent: http://happybase.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user.html#using-the-connection-pool